# I use 'book' document class. However, an addition of extra page after every chapter is inconsistent

Tags: chapters, books

I am using a `book` document class. I use `\include{}` to include a chapter. I checked the spec, it says for book class an extra empty page is added after every chapter. However, what I observe is the empty pages are inconsistent. i.e at for some chapter empty pages are added and for some they aren't.

Comment: Use `\documentclass[openany]{book}`, but this will cause chapter pages to start on an even-numbered page as well.

Comment: empty pages are only added if needed to force the chapter opening page to be on a right hand (odd) page.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I checked what you said, it is exactly the same. I want to make it uniform, either empty pages need to be added or not added at all. Now, I came to know the exact problem and I guess this is a duplicate question is solved using openany.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : Than you.

Comment: openany is what you want then, The blank pages before chapters are not just added for no reason, they are only added to get the chapter opening on to the right. Why else would you want a blank? So always having a blank page serves no purpose.